# No puedo asignar a una variable el resultado de un recorrido hecho a un diccionario

Tags: python, bucle-for, diccionarios

Verán, tengo un diccionario bastante complejo, estuve intentando recorrerlo bastante tiempo, y cuando lo logré, y llegué a los valores que deseo, al intentar asignarlos a una variable, solo toma uno de los 2 juegos, abajo dejo el diccionario:

```
diccionario = {'Juegos': [{'Titulo': 'Dishonored', 'Lanzamiento': 2012, 'Genero': ['Sigilo', 'Accion'], 'Tags': ['Steampunk', 'Asesino']}, {'Titulo': 'Bioshock', 'Lanzamiento': 2007, 'Genero': ['FPS', 'RPG'], 'Tags': ['Steampunk', 'Terror']}]}
```

Para recorrerlo usé:

```
for clave in diccionario["Juegos"]:
    print(clave["Titulo"])
```

El print me da:

```
Dishonored
Bioshock
```

Intenté asignarle a la variable titulos el resultado del recorrido:

```
for clave in diccionario["Juegos"]:
titulos = clave["Titulo"]
```

Pero al hacerle print a titulos, en vez de darme todos los juegos, solo me dio el último, o sea, Bioshock

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el script del que hablas. Sin ver el código en cuestión, todo es pura especulación

Comment: @CandidMoe creo haber agregado todo el código que menciono, ¿A cual te refieres? Está el diccionario al que recorrí, agregué el procedimiento por el cual recorrí, y agregué como intenté asignarle a la variable Titulos, el resultado del recorrido

Comment: "cambie el print(clave["Titulo"]) por titulos = clave["Titulo]" ... Esa versión

Comment: Además el `for clave in lista[]:`  ... ¿no será `diccionario`?

Comment: @CandidMoe creo que ahí agregué y arregle lo que dijiste, si es diccionario, fue una confusión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu codigo si está bien, lo que pasa en tu output es que como recorres todo, al volver a encontrar uno nuevo, asigna nuevamente el resultado. Por lo que puedes hacer, es agregarlos a un arreglo y luego imprimirlos con el mismo ciclo

```
diccionario = {'Juegos': [{'Titulo': 'Dishonored', 'Lanzamiento': 2012, 'Genero': ['Sigilo', 'Accion'], 'Tags': ['Steampunk', 'Asesino']}, {'Titulo': 'Bioshock', 'Lanzamiento': 2007, 'Genero': ['FPS', 'RPG'], 'Tags': ['Steampunk', 'Terror']}]}

def main():
    titulos = []
    for clave in diccionario["Juegos"]:
        titulos.append(clave["Titulo"])
    printTitulos(titulos)
    
def printTitulos(titulos):
    for titulo in titulos:
        print(titulo)

main()
```

Porque asignar dos veces la variable en un ciclo, sobre escribe los valores existentes, ten cuidado al estar asignando variables en ciclos. Recuerda que un ciclo se ejecuta n cantidad de veces, por lo que si ejecutas el ciclo n cantidad de veces, re-escribes (no agregas) n cantidad de veces a la misma variable

EDITADO:
El ciclo `for`, de la forma en que lo usas, interactua entre cada elemento, por lo que al asignarle dentro del ciclo un valor `titulos = clave["Titulo"]` sobre escribes lo que `titulos` tenía previamente. Es por eso que cuando haces un `print(titulos)` solo te sale el último, ya que fue el último que el ciclo encontró, el último que el ciclo asignó

Comment: Hola, me funcionó, ¿me explicas el funcionamiento de def printTitulos? No lo termino de entender

Comment: @Kalio Con gusto, primero que nada, `printTitulos()` es solo un nombre random, le puse así para que entendieras que hace, recibe como parametros el arreglo que creamos `titulos ` que si lo imprimes antes de llamar al otro método, verás que se representa como `['Dishonored', 'Bioshock']` y para acceder a cada uno, usas la misma lógica que utilizas para recorrer el diccionario inicial, un for que interactue por cada elemento dentro del arreglo. Ciertamente el método está de mas, puedes copiar y pegar el ciclo dentro de ese método en el método `main()` y te da el mismo output, pero por entenderlo

Comment: -1. Se puede hacer con dos líneas: `for clave in diccionario["Juegos"]:
    print(clave["Titulo"])`

Comment: @CandidMoe el lo que busca es agregarlos a una variable para, talvez, usarlos luego, no solo imprimirlos y por la forma en que interactua en su ciclo, lo mejor es guardarlos en un arreglo. Ademas, el código que me muestras es el que el tiene en su pregunta

Comment: La pregunta del OP es ¿por qué pasa esto?. Su problema es que no entiende el `for` ni la asignación de variables. Lo que necesita es una explicación de esos conceptos elementales. Tu respuesta no aborda eso.

Comment: @CandidMoe Tienes razón que no explico eso, ya edito... Pero el quiere de igual manera los titulos, talvez para mostrar luego algo tipo *Los juegos existentes son...* y es lo que yo le ayudo a manejar, poder asignar sin sobre escribir su variable

Comment: Les agradezco a los 2, a pesar de que recién estoy aprendiendo el bucle for, considero que el remplazo de valores es una característica de todos los diccionarios, no del for como tal, me había pasado anteriormente de olvidarme que si no aplicas append al valor que quieres agregar este se remplaza al ya existente, las 2 respuestas me lo recordaron por igual, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Examinemos el código (corrigiendo la indentación):

```
for clave in diccionario["Juegos"]:
    titulos = clave["Titulo"]
```

El `for` itera sobre la lista de diccionarios. En cada iteración asigna a la variable `titulos` el título del juego en cuestión:

1. En la primera iteración, asigna `'Dishonored'` a `titulos`.
2. En la segunda iteración, asigna `'Bioshock'` a `titulos`, reemplazando el valor anterior.

Cuando termina el `for`, la variable `titulos` contiene el último valor asignado ('Bioshock').

Es asi como funciona.

Comment: Cito lo que pone en su pregunta... *Pero al hacerle print a titulos, en vez de darme todos los juegos, solo me dio el último, o sea, Bioshock*